# User control does not refresh

Tags: c#, onpaint

I have created a usercontrol to which you can add different timeslots. All timeslots together form a trip. The control should draw all timeslots relative to the width of the control. Color depending on `ActivityType`.

If I add the `TripActivity` in the Load method, the control works ok. 
If I however add a `TripActivity` later on, - By calling method `ActivityAdd` - the activity gets added to the Activiteiten list, but nothing changes : `TripTimebar_Paint` is not being called. Even with a `refresh()` or `invalidate()`.

Please help

Kind regards
Victor

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace VPBAdmin
{
    public partial class TripTimeBar : UserControl
    {
        public class TripActivity
        {
            public string ActivityType { get; set; }
            public int Status { get; set; } // 0 = not yet, 1 = busy, 2 = finished
            public DateTime PlannedStart { get; set; }
            public int PlannedDuration { get; set; }
            public DateTime PlannedEnd { get; set; }
            public DateTime RealStart { get; set; }
            public int RealDuration { get; set; }
            ublic DateTime RealEnd { get; set; }

            public TripActivity(string p_sType, int p_iStatus, DateTime p_dtPlannedStart, int p_iPlannedDuration,
            DateTime p_dtPlannedEnd, DateTime p_dtRealStart, int p_iRealDuration, DateTime p_dtRealEnd)
            {
                ActivityType = p_sType;
                Status = p_iStatus;
                PlannedStart = p_dtPlannedStart;
                PlannedDuration = p_iPlannedDuration;
                PlannedEnd = p_dtPlannedEnd;
                RealStart = p_dtRealStart;
                RealDuration = p_iRealDuration;
                RealEnd = p_dtRealEnd;
            }

        }


        public string Trip { get; set; }
        private List<TripActivity> Activiteiten ;

        public TripTimeBar()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Activiteiten = new List<TripActivity>();

        }

        public void ActivityAdd(string p_sType, int p_iStatus, DateTime p_dtPlannedStart, int p_iPlannedDuration,
        DateTime p_dtPlannedEnd, DateTime p_dtRealStart, int p_iRealDuration, DateTime p_dtRealEnd)
        {
            TripActivity ta = new TripActivity(p_sType, p_iStatus, p_dtPlannedStart, p_iPlannedDuration,
            p_dtPlannedEnd, p_dtRealStart, p_iRealDuration, p_dtRealEnd);
            Activiteiten.Add(ta);

            Invalidate();

        }


        private void TripTimeBar_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Activiteiten.Add(new TripActivity("1", 0, DateTime.Now, 30, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, 0, DateTime.Now));
            Activiteiten.Add(new TripActivity("2", 0, DateTime.Now, 10, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, 0, DateTime.Now));
            Activiteiten.Add(new TripActivity("3", 0, DateTime.Now, 8, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, 0, DateTime.Now));
            Activiteiten.Add(new TripActivity("2", 0, DateTime.Now, 26, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, 0, DateTime.Now));
            Activiteiten.Add(new TripActivity("1", 0, DateTime.Now, 24, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, 0, DateTime.Now));
        }

        private void TripTimeBar_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Activiteiten.Count == 0) return;
            if (Width < 1) return;
            SolidBrush redBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
            SolidBrush blueBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.SlateGray);
            SolidBrush greenBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);
            SolidBrush currentBrush;
            int l_iWidth = Width;
            int l_iHeight = Height;
            int l_iNrActivities = Activiteiten.Count;
            int l_iTotalDuration = Activiteiten.Select(x =>     x.PlannedDuration).Sum();
            int l_iXPlanned = 0, l_iXReal = 0;
            // De hele breedte is gelijk aan het totaal aantal minuten.
            double l_dDivFactor = (double)l_iWidth / (double)l_iTotalDuration;
            foreach (TripActivity ta in Activiteiten)
            {
                int l_iActivityWidth = (int)(ta.PlannedDuration * l_dDivFactor);
                switch (ta.ActivityType)
                {
                    case "1":
                        currentBrush = redBrush;
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        currentBrush = blueBrush;
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        currentBrush = greenBrush;
                        break;
                    default:
                        currentBrush = redBrush;
                        break;
                }
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(currentBrush, new Rectangle(l_iXPlanned, 0, l_iActivityWidth, l_iHeight));
                l_iXPlanned += l_iActivityWidth;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Paint code is hard to debug.  Add Debug.Print() statements so you can trace it.  You'll at least want to ensure that the rectangles are good, the "duration" stuff does not look very healthy.

Comment: Thanks. It looks as if I found the problem. There were some issues in the designer file.